# Mask containing pattern not working in SVG

Tags: svg

Based on this example: https://bl.ocks.org/jfsiii/7772281

I am trying to fill an SVG shape with a masked pattern.
I have two boxes.  The first takes just the dot pattern.  This works, but the color of the dots cannot be changed in css.

I have a second box, which has a fill and is then masked with the same pattern.  This ought to result in blue dots.

But it's not masking properly.  Or at least, it's doing so inconsistently.  The first box will show in Chrome, but the second one will not, at least not until I go to inspect it.  Then it decides to turn on. :/.  Both show up in Firefox correctly.

Since the example I borrowed from works fine in Chrome, I assume I am doing something wrong.

```
<style>
      .mask-dots {
        mask: url(#mask-dots);
      }      
      .pattern-dots {
        fill: url(#pattern-dots)
      }

      .blue {
        fill: blue;
</style>

<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="393px"
     height="528px" viewBox="0 0 393 528" enable-background="new 0 0 393 528" xml:space="preserve">
<g id="underskirt-4">
      <rect  class="pattern-dots" width="100" height="100"/>
    <rect x="110" class="blue mask-dots" width="100" height="100"/>
</g>
</svg>
<svg><defs><pattern id="pattern-dots" width="50" height="50" 
          patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
         <path fill="white" d="M15.946,12.651c0,1.905-1.544,3.45-3.45,3.45c-0.953,0-1.815-0.386-2.439-1.011
    c-0.624-0.624-1.01-1.486-1.01-2.439c0-1.905,1.544-3.45,3.45-3.45S15.946,10.746,15.946,12.651z"/>
     </pattern>
        <mask id="mask-dots">
          <rect x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" fill="url(#pattern-dots)" />
        </mask>             
      </defs>
</svg>
```

Jsfiddle, with second box not displaying (at least not in Chrome.)
https://jsfiddle.net/qux8yt9g/

Comment: Presumably a Chrome bug, report it to their bugtracker

Comment: Working in Edge and Firefox 47. Chrome 51 seems to have a problem with the division into two SVG sections. Working as a single SVG in Chrome https://jsfiddle.net/qux8yt9g/1/ Probably Chrome shows the first SVG before it load the second. Do everything in a single SVG section then there are no problems.